# How to find non-disabled elements in a form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm now doing it this way:

```
$form.find(':input')
```

But how do exclude those disabled elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:enabled`

```
$form.find(':input:enabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use

```
$(':input:enabled',$('#FormID'));
```

or

```
$('#FormID :input:enabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be useful to post a simple variation here, taking a cue from the code snippet above.  I wanted to find if a particular element was enabled:

```
var firstNameEnabled = $('.firstName:input:enabled').length > 0;
```

Now `firstNameEnabled` will be true false, depending on the state the field has