# JQuery ignore disabled radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that is called on submit, which checks that each Radio button is checked.

```
$("input:radio").each(function() {
    var val = $('input:radio[id=' + this.id + ']:checked').val();
```

How can I modify this so that it excludes disabled values? (i.e. If the checkbox is disabled then ignore it)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find non-disabled elements in a form with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440190/how-to-find-non-disabled-elements-in-a-form-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:radio:enabled')
```

http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try exluding them with `.not("input[disabled]")`?

**edit**
Or what @Felix King said above!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.not()` function along with the `:disabled` selector, like this:

```
$("input:radio").not(':disabled').each(function() {
    // do whatever
});
```

Also as a note for your selector inside the function, use an ID selector if you have an ID; it's going to be much faster than using a tag name, tag type and attribute equals selector combination.